# Setting consistency level using Kundera Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, consistency, kundera

How can i set the Consistency level to quorum using Kundera Cassandra using external config files ?
we can do that wihthout external config files using:-
    Map propertyMap = new HashMap();
        propertyMap.put(CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION,
                CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION_3_0);
        propertyMap.put("consistency.level",ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);

but i want to use external configuration file.

Comment: well i found the solution to this :- we can set the consistency level Using JPA we can set additional properties within @PersistenceContext annotation:
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, properties = {
        @PersistenceProperty(name = "consistency.level", value="QUORUM")
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem consists in setting the consistency level using the Java Persistence API (JPA).

It is possible to set additional properties within `@PersistenceContext` annotation:

```
 @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, properties = { @PersistenceProperty(name = "consistency.level", value="QUORUM") })
```